# Email relaying with php | craigslist's anonymous email generator

Tags: php, mysql, email, smtp, craigslist

I wanted to create (or at least learn/know how it is done) application(or configuration?) that does similar to what craigslist does when people choose to hide their email with the "anonymous" option when making posts. I suspect that it is done with what's called email relaying. I'd like to find out how it is done in process - from when user enter their email to receiving an email via an anonymous email address. I come from a "LAMP" background at an intermediate level so please bear with me and kindly explain.

Your responses/comments/suggestions/pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any specific questions? Because that makes it a whole lot easier to answer them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to receive email with your php app. There are a wide range of ways to do this, collecting using cron, piping from an email server directly into your app or using a third party like [CloudMailin](http://cloudmailin.com).

I wrote a blog post explaining some of the methods you can use to receive incoming email using php [here](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/). The post discusses rails but the principals are the same for most languages and frameworks.

Comment: Thanks Steve! So better to look into php imap?

Comment: PHP Imap or Pop would work for you. Also I don't know how you're hosting but I've heard that cpanel can do the piping thing for email directly to the app. They're not massively scalable but could easily be enough to get you going.

Comment: Steve, I think I've got a good lead here from you, I'll do some research, and ultimately learn how to configure this. Thank you so much for your responses. I'll make sure to share once I have working examples...